# Rails ActiveRecord Object - modify one filed in return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My model Client returns a list of clients. One of the fields in client is created_at, which is returned for example like this 2017-06-13T13:59:36.000-03:00

I would like to return the datetime in a different format. In my view I would simply do `strftime("%I:%M")`, but in this case it's an API and I would like to return the datetime in the correct format already.

I would like to restrict this formatting to one controller (the API controller) only.

Can this be done?

Comment: `client.created_at.strftime("%I:%M")` would work.

Comment: Use this website - http://www.strfti.me/

Comment: Yeah, you dont need to format the date on the View , you can , too, do it as Zulhilmi said, on the controller for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using something like jbuilder, you'd do something like:

`json.created_at client.created_at.strftime("%I:%M")`

You could also define a method in your model that formats these dates such as:

```
def formatted_created_at
  created_at.strftime("%I:%M")
end
```

and in your serializer or jbuilder you'd have something like `client.formatted_created_at`